# User directory inside home directory MISSING

Tags: partitioning, 19.04, inode

I tried resizing the partitions while the system was on and when  I restarted the system, I was unable to login. Eventually when I could, I couldn't find my data. Since I haven't reinstalled the system and also I just resized the partitions , so will the data still be on the hard drive?

Comment: Please specify your OS/release detail; you have tagged an *end-of-life* release I note though.  It may depend on how you re-installed, did you format (thus erasing prior data), or use options that doesn't erase data (no-format was used)

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 19.04
Release: 19.04

Comment: I didn't re-install my system. There were errors like partition mount doesn't exist, PCie bus error. I solved those errors and finally I created a user directory(it wasn't there), created a .Xauthority file and I could login again. But to my dismay, I couldn't find any of my files. Can you please suggest me on where I should look for it?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: A non-boot after partition re-size maybe caused by moving the /boot/grub/ location on disk, so stage 1 of grub could have been pointing to an invalid location (did you correct that? with `grub-install`? as you haven't said). Either way you mention changes (.Xauthority) that I cannot see how it relates to a partition move, nor your issue (thus I suspect more than you've given), but you are using a unsupported & off-topic release so a re-install using 'something-else' of 19.10, using existing partitions ensuring you don't format maybe called for. Backup using a 'live' media first.